# I was trying to run simple HTML code on vs but this keeps poping up

Tags: html, visual-studio

Simple HTML code that would not run because of some issue

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the live server extension?

Comment: What is a live server extension?

Comment: A live server extension is a Web Extension that helps you to live reload feature for dynamic content. You could install it by clicking on the extensions icon in vscode and type 'live server' in the search bar and the very first option should be the one you install and then from there, it has the steps on how to load it.